# Should I be concerned about disable SELinux?

Tags: selinux

```
** (gnome-system-monitor:18284): WARNING **: SELinux was found but is not enabled.
```

Comment: Only if you need [SELinux](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). If you don't know what it is, you most likely don't need it.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't enable SELinux, but other distros, like Fedora do. If you're on Fedora or the like (presumably you aren't), it might be a cause for concern.

Answer (score 2):

SELinux is a security feature for Linux distributions.  It is not typically used in Ubuntu, which includes a different product, apparmor, which has similar goals.

These tools put restrictions on what various applications (such as daemons) can do, in order to provide additional security against intrusion.

Apparmor is enabled by default in Ubuntu but some profiles are not enforced.

[More information about Apparmor is available here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor).

Answer (score -1):

Don't install selinux there is a bug that doesn't load selinux properly.
But, install apparmor

`sudo apt-cache search apparmor`

`sudo apt-get install apparmor`

`sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils`

`sudo apt-get install apparomr-profiles`

Comment: AppArmor is enabled by default.

Comment: That's weird sometimes I had to install apparmor?

Comment: I am getting apparmor enabled message at boot and it enforces home directory policy.